# Fixed data type in SQL(ite3)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite, sqldatatypes

```
CREATE TABLE d_t (Date text);
```

.

```
INSERT INTO d_t(Date) VALUES (123)
```

Table:

---

> Date
>
> 123

*is there is any solution so that it doesn't accept any data type other than the specified data type?*

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, unless you have defined a column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, you can store any data type.

If you plan to store dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` or timestamps in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, you can prevent invalid values with a `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE d_t (Date text, CHECK (Date LIKE '____-__-__' AND date(Date) IS NOT NULL));
```

Or for timestamps:

```
CREATE TABLE d_t (Date text, CHECK (Date LIKE '____-__-__ __:__:__' AND datetime(Date) IS NOT NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container.](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

So an SQLite column is allowed to store different data types.
This is a valid set of INSERTs

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    t  TEXT,     -- text affinity by rule 2
    nu NUMERIC,  -- numeric affinity by rule 5
    i  INTEGER,  -- integer affinity by rule 1
    r  REAL,     -- real affinity by rule 4
    no BLOB      -- no affinity by rule 3
)
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(datetime('2021-05-25 14:30:15'), datetime('2021-05-25 14:30:15'), datetime('2021-05-25 14:30:15'), datetime('2021-05-25 14:30:15'),datetime('2021-05-25 14:30:15'));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(500, 500, 500, 500, 500);
INSERT INTO t1(i) VALUES('SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container.');
```